# jQuery drag and drop hyperlink generation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to use a jQuery-UI drag-and-drop system that I just ran across from [here](http://www.elated.com/res/File/articles/development/javascript/jquery/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/card-game.html).

My idea of using this drag-and-drop is to be able to combine 5 different products by dragging them to the container and produce a hyperlink for each different combination. Here is a picture of the basic idea:

[image: Basic idea]

There would be a button or something next to it and once the user is happy with the combination by clicking on the button next to it it would send him/her to the specific hyperlink.

My question is:

- Can I replace numbers by names (eg. BUTTER, MILK, MEAT, EGGS, FLOUR)?

  ```
  // Create the pile of shuffled cards
     var numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
     numbers.sort( function() { return Math.random() - .5 } );

   for ( var i=0; i<5; i++ ) {
  $('<div>' + numbers[i] + '</div>').data( 'number', numbers[i] ).attr( 'id', 'card'+numbers[i] ).appendTo( '#cardPile' ).draggable( {
    containment: '#content',
    stack: '#cardPile div',
    cursor: 'move',
    revert: true
  } );
  }
  ```
- Is it possible to generate the hyperlink according to the order of dropped "ingredients"? I mean if we drop BREAD, EGGS, BUTTER -> bread-eggs-butter.html and if we drop EGGS-BUTTER-BREAD -> eggs-butter-bread.html.
- Is this even possible in jQuery?

Here is my not-yet-working point in [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/3eZH084IWi1KkEzKbS07?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Since this gets more complicated than a simple answer here, I'll show you an example.

If you have your HTML like so:

```
<div class="take">
    <div class="ingredient" id="ing-1">Ingredient 1</div>
    <div class="ingredient" id="ing-2">Ingredient 2</div>
    <div class="ingredient" id="ing-3">Ingredient 3</div>
    <div class="ingredient" id="ing-4">Ingredient 4</div>
    <div class="ingredient" id="ing-5">Ingredient 5</div>
</div>
<div class="place">
    <div class="spot" id="spot-1"></div>
    <div class="spot" id="spot-2"></div>
    <div class="spot" id="spot-3"></div>
    <div class="spot" id="spot-4"></div>
    <div class="spot" id="spot-5"></div>
</div>
```

And you want to drag your ingredients to your "place" container

```
$('.ingredient').draggable();

$('.spot').droppable({
    drop: function(){
        var all_ingredients = []; //initiate a blank array
        $('.place .spot').each(function(){
            var ingredient = $(this).find('.ingredient').attr('id').replace("ing-", "");
            all_ingredients.push(ingredient); //push each ingredient in the order that it's placed
        });

        var url = all_ingredients.join("-") + ".html"; //Make a URL string
    }
});
```

**UPDATED**

I added some code to your plunker and you can see the output in the console:

```
var all_ingredients = [];
$('#cardSlots > div').each(function(i){
    if($(this).hasClass('ui-droppable-disabled')){
        var ingredient = $(this).text();
        all_ingredients.push(ingredient);
    }
  });
console.log(all_ingredients);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Huo1VGFFC8xH7A9XkQWQ?p=preview

Comment: Hi ntgCleaner. Thank you very much for your answer and correcting the question. I just tried your answer in plnkr.co but haven't reached the desired result yet. It seems very reasonable. I'm just wandering is this the complete code? would you be willing to insert it in this plnkr. and fork it? http://plnkr.co/edit/3eZH084IWi1KkEzKbS07?p=preview

Comment: @matus, I'll take a look at the plnkr.co link you have and see if I can come up with something

Comment: @matus Please check out this link: http://plnkr.co/edit/Huo1VGFFC8xH7A9XkQWQ?p=preview Line 78 is where it starts. Please take a look at the console when testing.

Comment: thank you again for editing the plnkr. I tried it many times. it seems it's producing the same effect as the original one. what exactly am i suppose to pay attention to? as soon as I drop all the numbers to right slots it gets me the success message and I can play it again. I have been trying hard to combine your original answer of take-place ingredients with the plnkr but no success there yet. I appreciate your time.

Comment: i think this might be better to represent what i\m intending to do... http://plnkr.co/edit/pZYxUWDQeoDGnsGRm7x6?p=preview